# ../golang/pkg/mod/github.com/wmentor/lemmas@v0.0.6/processor.go:72:9: undefined: tokens.Process

Tags: golang

установил [библиотеку](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/wmentor/lemmas#section-readme)

попробовал запустить пример

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"

  "github.com/wmentor/lemmas"
)

func main() {

  txt := "Создать экспертную систему."

  processor := lemmas.New()

  processor.AddText(strings.NewReader(txt))

  processor.FetchResult(func(keyphrase string, weight float64) {
    fmt.Println(keyphrase, weight)
  })
}
```

выдаёт ошибку

```
../golang/pkg/mod/github.com/wmentor/lemmas@v0.0.6/processor.go:72:9: undefined: tokens.Process
```

у кого было подобное? Как лечить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что в инструкции написано `go get -u github.com/wmentor/lemmas`. Ключик `-u` означает *скачать самую свежую версию зависимостей*. В случае с `lemmas` это приводит к тому, что вместо `github.com/wmentor/tokens v1.0.4` скачивается `github.com/wmentor/tokens v1.0.7` где, как ни странно, отсутствует функция `tokens.Process` (хотя по распространённому мнению изенение третьей циферки версии не должно привносить breaking changes).

Вот как выглядят зависимости в `go.mod` после `go get -u`:

```
require (
    github.com/wmentor/html v1.0.3 // indirect
    github.com/wmentor/lemmas v0.0.6 // indirect
    github.com/wmentor/tbuf v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/wmentor/tokens v1.0.7 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.20.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.14.0 // indirect
)
```

а вот так после `go get`:

```
require (
    github.com/wmentor/html v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/wmentor/lemmas v0.0.6 // indirect
    github.com/wmentor/tokens v1.0.4 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200301022130-244492dfa37a // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.2 // indirect
)
```

Нужно устанавливать командой `go get github.com/wmentor/lemmas`, без `-u`. Тогда `lemmas` будет версии 1.0.4 и всё успешно скомпилируется.